# Yup form validation where one of two fields is required

Tags: typescript, forms, material-ui, formik, yup

I'm looking to use Yup to setup a validation schema where a user must select one of two options from the form. If they do not, the form should provide an error message.

Users should be able to enter their own value (in a TextField) or select the maxValue (in a Checkbox). I'm using formik.

I attempted to create a custom Yup test in my validation schema below:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object()
  .shape({
    name: Yup.string().required("A name is required"),
    userValue: Yup.string(),
    maxValue: Yup.boolean(),
  })
  .test(
    "valueOrMax",
    "Either a value must be entered or the maximum must be selected",
    function (value) {
      const { userValue, maxValue } = this.parent;
      if (userValue.length === 0 && !maxValue) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  );
```

I thought I'd be able to access this error message using errors.valueOrMax, but this is not working. No error messages are showing up when the user neither enters a value or selects the checkbox.

```
<Formik<InitialValues>
          initialValues={initialValues}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
          {({
            errors,
            handleBlur,
            handleChange,
            handleSubmit,
            touched,
            values,
          }) => {
              <form
                onSubmit={() => {
                  console.log("entered submit");
                  handleSubmit();
                }}
              >
                      <FormControl 
                        fullWidth
                        error={Boolean((touched.userValue || touched.maxValue) && errors.valueOrMax)}
                      >
                        <TextField
                          name="userValue"
                          type="text"
                          fullWidth
                          disabled={values.maxValue}
                          value={values.userValue}
                          onChange={handleChange}
                          onBlur={handleBlur}
                          InputProps={{
                            inputComponent: TextMaskCustom,
                          }}
                        />
                        <FormControlLabel
                          control={
                            <Checkbox
                              name="maxValue"
                              checked={values.maxValue}
                              onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                          }
                          label="Max value"
                        />
                        <FormHelperText error>
                           {touched.userValue || touched.maxValue) && errors.valueOrMax}
                        </FormHelperText>
                      </FormControl>
             </form>
```

I'm happy to have a better recommendation on how to accomplish this and can provide more context from the code if necessary.